# Why are static variable data lost and not instance when restarting IIS/app pool recycling?

Tags: c#, iis, static

Why is that if I restart IIS, a static variable's data is lost (e.g. in a webpart property in Sharepoint) but in an instance variable, this is not the case?

This is with IIS7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.

Thanks

Comment: you mean instance variables within a process live on after the complete process has died (which bascially happens when recycling/restarting) ? ***Really ? Really ? Really ?*** IF so please tell how to reproduce that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a process is restarted, *all* variables are lost.
But: IIS automatically serializes the session variables into another processes memory when a pool is recyled. When the pool restarts, the session variables are deserialized and thus, restored.
This is done with the .NET serialisation feature, which means that all session variables has to be marked with the [Serializable] attribute, otherwise you get runtime excpetions.

Comment: Thanks for this post, very informative. Where did you find that out?

Answer (score 3):

Instance variables *will* certainly be lost - it's just that presumably they're being repopulated via request data, just as they are when IIS *isn't* restarted.